# Here Maps REST API - getlinkinfo returns incorrect speed limit

Tags: api, rest, here-api

I have been using the getlinkinfo command to look at speed limits.  The  values returned by the API appear to be reduced by a factor of 3.6 relative to posted speed limits on roads in my community.  For example, here is a request for a road segment of Highway 101 in Fredericton, NB, Canada that has a posted speed Limit of 90 kph:

http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.xml?app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&waypoint=45.921339,-66.666753&linkattributes=sc,sl

(Short link - http://goo.gl/EWfKDe)

```
This request returns a speed limit of "25" and the actual posted speed limit is 90. Can you tell me why the <SpeedLimit> values do not contain the actual posted speed limit?  Is it because I am using the "DemoAppId"?
```

Bernie.

Answer (score 9):

The `speedLimit` element is always returned in **m/s** so you'll need to use a conversion factor to obtain to the typical road sign units. Multiply by 3.6 for **km/h** or 2.23 for **mph**. If the `speedLimit` element is missing then the national speed limit applies.

Why chose **m/s** you may ask? I reckon this has been done to avoid rounding errors in calculations by consistently using the smallest distance unit (metre) and the smallest time unit (second) across the HERE platform. I assume that the data underlying `getlinkinfo` is used when calculating routes.

A [working example](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#speed-limit-on-click__index) can be found on the HERE Maps Community Examples on GitHub

Comment: Thank for for the answer -- that 3.6 was driving me crazy. A couple of points: a lot of the here github resources still have nokia in the URL, which means they are broken; and it would be nice if the API docs were more explicit about using m/s. It is perfectly reasonable, but I don't see it explicitly stated on the demo page: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/routing/link-information-for-a-location. The roads.googleapis.com service explicitly returns the units.