# Leaflet JS, Get the road speed limit

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am using [LeafletJS](http://leafletjs.com) with OpenStreetMap . I would to know if I can get the road speed limit (The maximum legal speed on the street) .

For example I can do it like this in [google play maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits) :

```
roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?parameters&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

**Is there any method or plugin for Leaflet to get that info ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet only displays maps, is provider-agnostic, and doesn't handle data queries.

You'll have to rely on a data provider which has maximum speed data for the roads (osm, google, here, bing, etc). One of your best bets is going to be OpenStreetMap through the OverPass API, see «[get speed limits from OpenStreetMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749133/get-speed-limits-from-openstreetmap)»